# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, audiotoolbox

I'm working on a Custom Alarm App and want to use Vibration in my App as soon as the alarm plays and I have used AudioToolbox and used this below code:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

and it worked but i want to run continuously vibration in my App.

is there any possible way to implement this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to repeat your vibration request.

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector:@selector(repeat:) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];

```
-(void)repeat:(id)sender{

  AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSTimer and call your function which contain vibration code and when you want to stop it you can call NSTimer's release method.

Example code :

```
    NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                                  target: self
                                                selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                                userInfo: nil repeats:NO];

    -(void)onTick:(id)sender{

        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

    }
```

This code will vibrate device continuously with delay of 2 seconds.
when you want to stop vibration you can call release method.

```
Ex. [t release];
```

Comment: Thanks!! i am trying this